# Manga about a boy who died on his way to school who has to win battles to be resurrected

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga I read about 8-9 years ago.

The MC was a male high school kid that woke up on his birthday. As he was running to school he all of a sudden he was in the hallway of his school doing magic tricks to his friends. When he went to the bathroom there was a number on his forehead that no one else could see.

When he arrived home a demon girl told him that he had died on his way to school and he had a chance to be resurrected. All he had to do was win a certain amount of battles with other characters. He also learned that each "character" had special powers based on what they were good at when they were alive. He then fought this guy who was good at roller skating and beat him.

I can't remember the name, the author or anything, and I have looked for hours using key words to try to find it... I read it on a manga app.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If someone post the correct answer, you can accept by clicking the check mark by the answer, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [13 Game](https://myanimelist.net/manga/37677/13_Game). From My Anime List:

> On his seventeenth birthday, Amamiya Kota was going to ask his classmate Misora Hiyori out. Tragically, he dies in a car accident but is given a second chance back in the living world on borrowed time. He gets entered into a competition called the 13 Game where other people like Kota who were supposed to die return back to the world and given an option: locate and kill 13 other players or suffer the fate of death. Each player is assigned to a handler, mysterious beings with special powers, who use them as if they were characters in a video game. Kota's handler, Merume, explains that there are players like him all over the country, each with a unique ability that helps them kill, and Kota has to kill 13 players within 1 year. With his demon hands ability that was inspired from his hobby of magic tricks, Kota must unwillingly participate in this cruel game if he wants to live.

The manga starts as you remember, with Amamiya Kouta walking to school on his 17th birthday, performing magic tricks for his friends, finding a strange number on his forehead and having to defeat an in-line skater.